# Auto scroll when selected in TabView

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, tabs

I have a tab layout which it contains many tabs so I want to scroll between them.
I tried `HorizontalScrollView`and it's ok but when I change layouts by scrolling between them the Tab layout doesn't scroll automatically to show the selected tab.
Can I fix this by just XML ?
here is my code :

```
 <HorizontalScrollView 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:scrollbars="">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1):

found the solution! just remove `HorizontalScrollView` and add this to the TabLayout :

```
  app:tabMode="scrollable"
```